# How to add padding to the android screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

I want to add black padding (a thick black border) to the android screen such that every app is displayed with the padding around it. I know how to do this for my app but how do I do this such that when my app is running in background the display is padded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible unless you're willing to create and run a custom ROM.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully, this is not possible for the average non-ROM third party Android developer.

The screen on mobile devices is actually very limited, and when programming for the mobile environment, you have to learn to get away from the windows metaphor used by traditional desktop PCs.

On the other hand, may be your app could pretend it is running in the background, but still stay in the foreground with its transparency enabled. And perhaps if you can't do something, may be you can find a way to fake that something for your users.

Also, note that the default home launcher is capable of doing something similar to what you want, but only for widgets. And if being able to run widgets is sufficient for you, perhaps you could write your own launcher application that can embed widgets.